# Pass Json data to another route template in angular js

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular-ui-router

After login I want to pass the user details to dashboard?How it possible in angular js?

### Login.js

```
mySchoolApp.controller('loginController', ['$scope', '$http', function($scope, $http) {     
        this.loginForm = function() {           
        let encodedString = 'uname=' +this.username +'&pwrd=' +this.password;           
            sessionStorage.user = encodedString;
            console.log(sessionStorage.user)
            window.location.href = 'dashboard.html';            
        }
    }]);
```

In console I'm getting the value.
How to get the user details in dashboard.html page?

Comment: That isn't really how angular is designed to work.  You should be using `ng-route` (or it's replacement, `ui-router`) instead of referring to a new page. Angular is a Single Page Application framework, and that you should have a single *page* which is composed from multiple *views*.

Answer (score 0):

You should use router module `ui-router` or `ng-router` in order to use angualrjs logic in that sense but then your pages are going to be loaded via ajax and regular session http authentication can not be applied.
If that's the case then use `angular service provider` and let me know to edit my answer.

If you'd like to keep data across pages and not using database or server.
Then what is left as options are: [sessionStorage](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/API/Window/sessionStorage) and [localStorage](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/API/Window/localStorage).
The localStorage keeps data permanently until  browser cache deletes it while the other one obviously for the session.

```
sessionStorage.setItem('myCat', 'Tom');
```

If you want to keep js collection like object or array first stringify it:

```
var user = {pass:'moo', name: 'boo'};
sessionStorage.setItem('userDetais', JSON.stringify(user));
```

Answer (score 0):

You should use `ng-route` to achieve this.Angular isn't designed to work like this 
Here is sample

```
$stateProvider
    .state('app', {
        abstract: true,
      url: "",
      template: '<ui-view/>'
    })
    .state('app.home', {
      url: "/",
      templateUrl: "partials/main_page.html",
      resolve: {
        skipIfLoggedIn: skipIfLoggedIn
      }
    }).state('app.dashboard', {
      url: "/dashboard",
      templateUrl: "partials/dashboard.html",
      controller: 'DashboardCtrl',
      activePage:'dashboard',
      resolve: {
        loginRequired: loginRequired
      }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can store it in a `localstorage`.So you can use [**angular-local-storage**](https://github.com/grevory/angular-local-storage) Angular module for that.

How to set :

```
myApp.controller('MainCtrl', function($scope, localStorageService) {
  //...
  function submit(key, val) {
   return localStorageService.set(key, val);
  }
  //...
});
```

How to Get :

```
myApp.controller('MainCtrl', function($scope, localStorageService) {
  //...
  function getItem(key) {
   return localStorageService.get(key);
  }
  //...
});
```

Comment: the localStorage module isn't likely to help, since the way this code is structured, these pages are different angular apps.

Comment: @Claies But it stores data locally within the user's browser no ? Then how that matters ?